# How to output singleton pvalue to console in Beam?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I try to output the result `spammers_view` of `as_singleton_view()` to console, per [codes](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/game/game_stats.py#L334)

```py
    # Calculate the total score per user over fixed windows, and cumulative
    # updates for late data
    spammers_view = (
        user_events
        | 'UserFixedWindows' >> beam.WindowInto(
            beam.window.FixedWindows(fixed_window_duration))

        # Filter out everyone but those with (SCORE_WEIGHT * avg) clickrate.
        # These might be robots/spammers.
        | 'CalculateSpammyUsers' >> CalculateSpammyUsers()

        # Derive a view from the collection of spammer users. It will be used as
        # a side input in calculating the team score sums, below
        | 'CreateSpammersView' >> beam.CombineGlobally(
            beam.combiners.ToDictCombineFn()).as_singleton_view())
```

what I have tried

1st try

```py
          | 'debug_output' >> beam.Map(debug_collect)

    ...
    def debug_print(row):
       print(row)
```

2nd try

```py
      (spammers_view | 'debug_print' >> PrintTran())

class PrintTran(beam.PTransform):
    def expand(self, data):
        print(pvalue.AsIteor(data))
```

However, the following exception comes up

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 896, in __ror__
    return self.transform.__ror__(pvalueish, self.label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 506, in __ror__
    for ix, v in enumerate(pvalues)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/ptransform.py", line 507, in <dictcomp>
    if not isinstance(v, pvalue.PValue) and v is not None}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/transforms/core.py", line 2213, in __init__
    self.values = tuple(values)
TypeError: 'AsSingleton' object is not iterable
```

Beam version: 2.14.0

How to output singleton value to console in Beam?

Answer (score 1):

Your combiner results in a `PCollection` with a single element. So you can just send that through a `Map` step to print that value. For example,

```py
    spammers_view = (
        user_events
        | 'UserFixedWindows' >> beam.WindowInto(
            beam.window.FixedWindows(fixed_window_duration))

        # Filter out everyone but those with (SCORE_WEIGHT * avg) clickrate.
        # These might be robots/spammers.
        | 'CalculateSpammyUsers' >> CalculateSpammyUsers()

        # Derive a view from the collection of spammer users. It will be used as
        # a side input in calculating the team score sums, below
        | 'CreateSpammersView' >> beam.CombineGlobally(
            beam.combiners.ToDictCombineFn())
        | 'debug_output' >> beam.Map(debug_collect))

    def debug_collect(value):
      print(value)
```

You can Replace `beam.Map` with a `ParDo` transform if needed.

Note that since you use `ToDictCombineFn` as your combiner, this will print a dictionary of all key value pairs you fed into the combiner, and may fail if the number of input elements are too large.

Comment: thank you for your reponse. However, this error `ValueError: Default values are not yet supported in CombineGlobally() if the output  PCollection is not windowed by GlobalWindows. Instead, use CombineGlobally().without_defaults() to output an empty PCollection if the input PCollection is empty, or CombineGlobally().as_singleton_view() to get the default output of the CombineFn if the input PCollection is empty.` comes up following your codes...

Comment: After adding this codes `'CreateAbnormalView' >> beam.CombineGlobally(beam.combiners.ToDictCombineFn()).without_defaults()`, it seems works well...  replace `as_singleton_view ` with `without_defaults`

Comment: On the other side, we cannot print the result of `as_singleton_view`? or anything else I am missing